# Glide- How can I use Glide.clear() in Recycler Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I'm new at Glide. I want to use Glide.clear() function to clear memory and avoid OOM. But I don't know where I must use Glide.clear() in **RecyclerView Adapter** ? For example when an user close the app I want to call Glide.clear(). Also this is my Glide loading code in onBindViewHolder:

```
  Glide.with(context).load(ApiClient.Base_URL + imagesList.get(0).getImage())
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
                            .dontAnimate()
                            .dontTransform()
                            .thumbnail(0.1f)
                            .override(holder.deviceWitdh, holder.deviceHeight)
                            .error(R.drawable.error)
                            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                    holder.progresBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    return false;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                    holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    return false;
                                }
                            })
                            .into(holder.imageView);
```

Comment: Rather than trying to do this sort of thing manually, I recommend [configuring Glide's memory cache](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/configuration.html#memory-cache).

Comment: @CommonsWare but there is no content about Glide.clear() in the link.

Comment: That is because I am recommending that you not use `Glide.clear()`. I am recommending that you configure Glide's memory cache, so that Glide can clear its own memory better.

Comment: @CommonsWare it seems complex and also I'm new at Glide. So can you suggest me another ways?

Answer (score 1):

it is work for me :

```
Glide.with(context).load(Url).skipMemoryCache(true).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).into(img);
```